# Flip (Mirror) Image Java

Tags: java, arrays, methods, bufferedimage

I'm trying to mirror or flip an image but my code only mirrors half the image and I don't know how to fix it. This is the original image:
[original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eRE6G.png)
I'm trying to get this as my final result:
[flipped/mirrored image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/By0aS.png)

I also want to clarify that I know I can take advantage of 2DGraphics and the API support but I'm trying to figure out how I can mirror the image by manipulating the 2D array

This is my code and the result that I get:

```
public static void applyMirror(BufferedImage img) {
int width = img.getWidth();
int height = img.getHeight();
for(int j = 0; j < height; j++){
  for(int i = 0, w = width - 1; i < width; i++, w--){
    int p = img.getRGB(i, j);
    img.setRGB(w, j, p);
  }
}
```

[my result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9KIkB.png)

Comment: I like the half mirrored result.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please remember to read [how to ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask), which explains that you should not post images of code. Put the actual code in your post, and ideally, put enough code around it so that it's a [mcve].

Comment: For [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12432791/how-to-mirror-an-image-with-java-awt/12433025#12433025); [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11911610/affinetransform-rotate-how-do-i-xlate-rotate-and-scale-at-the-same-time/11911758#11911758); [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71280950/mirroring-an-image-in-java/71281068#71281068); [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72400698/imageio-write-a-mirrored-image-only-functional-in-png-in-java/72400831#72400831);

Comment: [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56283074/how-do-i-create-a-kaleidoscopic-photo-with-this/56283960#56283960)

Comment: @MadProgrammer of course, if any of those are duplicates, just vote to close as duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to walk for i upto width/2.
Otherwise you swap every (i, width - i - 1) twice. ;)

And swap the two opposite pixels.

–-----

### Code

```
for (int i = 0, w = width - 1; i < w; ++i, --w) {
    int pi = img.getRGB(i, j);
    int pw = img.getRGB(w, j);
    img.setRGB(i, j, pw);
    img.setRGB(w, j, pi);
}
```

This ensures you do not write an already changed pixel, as your code did.

Comment: So instead of i < width, I use i < width / 2 ? And could you clarify what you mean by swap the two opposite pixels?

Comment: `i` and `w` are the opposite positions. You want to swap/interchange those two pixels. As long as `i < w`.

Answer (score 1):

Simply make use of the available API support.  A really simple trick is to simply scale the image using a negative value in the axis you want mirrored, for example...

```
BufferedImage mirrored = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
Graphics2D g2d = mirrored.createGraphics();
g2d.scale(-1, 1);
g2d.translate(-source.getWidth(), 0);
g2d.drawImage(source, 0, 0, null);
g2d.dispose();
```

Not only is it faster, it's also a lot simpler

[image][image]

Comment: Yes, you are correct that method is a lot easier but I want to figure out how to mirror the image without the use of the API support.